# Sorting a fetch request based on count of related object in to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Need to sort a list of categories retrieved via fetch request in order by the number/count of products a category has. I'd then like the be able to manually add a couple of categories (which are filtered out) to the array, so that they're at the bottom of the list. I keep running into the error of "Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one..." when I try to sort by count of products.

What am I missing here/doing wrong? Thanks!

Category.h

```
@class Category;

@interface Category : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *products;

@end
```

Product.h

```
@class Category;

@interface Product : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sku;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; // Product name
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *prodDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Category *category; // Product category
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *upc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *countryCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *webpage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *manual;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *quickStart;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *thumb;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thumbURLString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *mainImg;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mainImgURLString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *secondaryImg;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *secondaryImgURLString;

@end
```

CategoriesViewController.m

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]]; // Fetch categories
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = nil;
        NSString *sectionNameKeyPath = nil;
        // Sort by number of products in category
        sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category.@count" ascending:NO]];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Use predicate to exclude Accessories and Replacement Parts categories from initial array
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != 'Accessories' AND name != 'Replacement Parts'"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath
                                                                               cacheName:nil];

        }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a to-many relationship like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is solved by having a count variable in the record itself. This allows the fetched results controller to sort on the value of that count. I maintain this kind of count in a custom setter for the relationship in question. In your case, that is probably the set of `products` and the new variable might be called `productCount`. Xcode has a snippet template for this sort of thing. Here's an example:

```
- (void) addProductsObject: (Product *) value {

    NSSet *changedObjects = [NSSet setWithObject:value];

    [self willChangeValueForKey: kDays withSetMutation: NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects: changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey: kDays] addObject: value];
    [self  didChangeValueForKey: kDays withSetMutation: NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects: changedObjects];

    self.productCount = (int32_t)self.products.count;

} // -addProductsObject:
```

The other three methods are similarly straightforward.